# Fiware sorts each request differently

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

When I send a request with Fiware orion-ld, it constantly changes the order. This needs to remain constant. What is the reason of this?

Sample data is as follows.

[
{
"id": "urn:ngsi-ld:yilliktopluenerjituketimi:2f63e178-4e0e-4319-a3b4-0f9814b097f5",
"type": "yilliktopluenerjituketimi",
"ay": "Şubat",
"co2EmisyonuDogalgazKgCo2": 25617.26832,
"co2EmisyonuElektrikKgCo2": 209561.884,
"co2EmisyonuYakitKgCo2": 26800,
"dogalgazKwh": 126818.16,
"elektrikKwh": 341306,
"yakitKwh": 76019.875,
"year": 2024
},
{
"id": "urn:ngsi-ld:yilliktopluenerjituketimi:ad3f268a-18ad-4c7c-b4ca-3a2f6ee284f5",
"type": "yilliktopluenerjituketimi",
"ay": "Ocak",
"co2EmisyonuDogalgazKgCo2": 25114.3368,
"co2EmisyonuElektrikKgCo2": 214071.1,
"co2EmisyonuYakitKgCo2": 30649.6,
"dogalgazKwh": 124328.4,
"elektrikKwh": 348650,
"yakitKwh": 86939.506,
"year": 2024
},
{
"id": "urn:ngsi-ld:yilliktopluenerjituketimi:7b218913-2c1b-46ef-9be7-29f15c9d8986",
"type": "yilliktopluenerjituketimi",
"ay": "Mart",
"co2EmisyonuDogalgazKgCo2": 28267.33056,
"co2EmisyonuElektrikKgCo2": 219725.426,
"co2EmisyonuYakitKgCo2": 31420.8,
"dogalgazKwh": 139937.28,
"elektrikKwh": 357859,
"yakitKwh": 89127.063,
"year": 2024
},
{
"id": "urn:ngsi-ld:yilliktopluenerjituketimi:79f29c7f-8373-4b66-b8cc-a1b4bb73be15",
"type": "yilliktopluenerjituketimi",
"ay": "Nisan",
"co2EmisyonuDogalgazKgCo2": 24282.56544,
"co2EmisyonuElektrikKgCo2": 205822.01,
"co2EmisyonuYakitKgCo2": 31305.6,
"dogalgazKwh": 120210.72,
"elektrikKwh": 335215,
"yakitKwh": 88800.291,
"year": 2024
},
{
"id": "urn:ngsi-ld:yilliktopluenerjituketimi:431af7d3-1a6f-43f0-945d-8d05a7433f47",
"type": "yilliktopluenerjituketimi",
"ay": "Mayıs",
"co2EmisyonuDogalgazKgCo2": 24705.9736,
"co2EmisyonuElektrikKgCo2": 201862.938,
"co2EmisyonuYakitKgCo2": 28041.6,
"dogalgazKwh": 122306.8,
"elektrikKwh": 328767,
"yakitKwh": 79541.751,
"year": 2024
},
{
"id": "urn:ngsi-ld:yilliktopluenerjituketimi:b61d84c1-5596-45dc-a4f2-6a71fc37e540",
"type": "yilliktopluenerjituketimi",
"ay": "Haziran",
"co2EmisyonuDogalgazKgCo2": 25890.22688,
"co2EmisyonuElektrikKgCo2": 217440.118,
"co2EmisyonuYakitKgCo2": 30758.4,
"dogalgazKwh": 128169.44,
"elektrikKwh": 354137,
"yakitKwh": 87248.124,
"year": 2024
}
]

Comment: I assume the output is from a GET /entities request. And I assume you're talking about the order of the entities, not the attributes inside the entities.   The entities are ordered by createdAt and there are hundreds of functional tests making sure that that order works.  So ... not sure what is going wrong here.  Perhaps some more information?
E.g., are you using a 'q' filter and you get different matching entities for every request?

Comment: Yes, I use the 'q' parameter according to the 'year' field. It doesn't matter which entity. We get a different order for each entity.  So when we fetch the data only from MongoDB, it doesn't perform any sorting

Comment: ok, that 'q' should not alter the order. Weird. I order the entities by createdAt ...   I need to look into this. If it's true what you say it's BAD !!!    Please create an issue about it on Orion-LD's github

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, maintaining an ordered list is not considered to be the job of a context broker. If you look at the current [1.7.1 NGSI-LD specification](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_gs/CIM/001_099/009/01.07.01_60/gs_cim009v010701p.pdf) from ETSI and look for the words *"sort"* or *"ordered"*, you'll find that maintaining order is simply not mentioned.

The reason for this is that a context broker is not a database. When you make an entity query such as `/entities?type=Sensor&q=temperature>30` the context broker will return everything it **locally** knows about `Sensors` with a `temperature` currently above 30, and also interrogate **remotely** all of it registered context sources about `Sensors` entities they know about which also have a `temperature` currently above 30.

This distributed nature leads to the following problem regarding sort. Firstly registered context sources can be independently updated, so the query must always be made across all sources. Secondly any registered context source could be currently unavailable and thirdly timing is such that any registered context source could respond back in any order.

Internally a context broker does its best to collate all this information and return its holistically correct representation of the state of the system right now. Adding in another sort step after that would slow the response time of the broker itself. It is not necessary in most applications.

Now your user-agent can order the entities in a context broker response itself with a single line of code like:

```js
ordered.sort((a, b) => a.id.localCompare(b.id));
```

Which doesn't add overhead to the broker, but does allow you to receive the data in a random order and make it consistent for you, in the manner that you require.

Besides which, which specific [collation sort order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_order) would you expect? ASCII? [German](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_orthography)? [Swedish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swedish_orthography)? [Lithuanian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithuanian_orthography)? All of these would result in a different order.

Since NGSI-LD doesn't mandate a specific backing database, you cannot make any inference about the default sort ordering that local entities are held.

Comment: There is one exception to this  lack of ordering - some core `@context`  keywords are defined in [JSON-LD syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld11/#sets-and-lists) using `@container: @list` - this maintains the order within that attribute. A good example of this is GeoJSON `coordinates` which always maintain the order Longitude, Latitude.

NGSI-LD payloads are always valid JSON-LD, and unless deliberately stated otherwise JSON-LD does not maintain order in any way.